# Removing all occurrences of '^' from a String

Tags: javascript, regex, angular, typescript

I have this sorta string = `"^My Name Is Robert.^"`
I want to remove the occurrences of ^ from this string. I tried the replace method like :

```
replyText.replace(/^/g, '');
```

But it hasn't any affect. Using the replace without the global works but only removes the first occurrence.

Should I just make a loop and keep looping the string with replace till no more '^' are contained, or is there a better way?

Comment: Escape `^` to make `/\^/g`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the ^ character in RegEx:

```
replyText.replace(/\^/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

*The caret*, `^`, is a special character in Regex, therefore it has to be escaped with a backslash i.e

`replyText.replace(/\^/g, '')`